# cast column to_date with multiple date formats in original text column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, date-conversion

I have a table with a `event_date text` column with values following one of two date formats:

1. 'YYYYMMDD'
2. 'YYYY-MM-DD'

For example:

| event_date: text |
| --- |
| 1991-04-01 |
| 2009-02-11 |
| 20010101 |
| NULL |
| 20020101 |

#### How might I parse that column into `Date` format?

Especially considering that [TO_DATE()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-formatting.html) will take only one possible format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both formats would be converted to dates with:

```
SELECT event_date::date event_date
FROM tablename;
```

Or use a `CASE` expression to choose one of the two formats:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
         event_date,
         CASE
           WHEN event_date LIKE '____-__-__' THEN 'YYYY-MM-DD'
           WHEN event_date LIKE '________' THEN 'YYYYMMDD'
         END
       ) event_date
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e4343ecd181dba12bf425fc5f7083c4b).

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain why the implicit conversion works for either case?

Comment: @JoeyBaruch Postgresql recognizes several formats and can convert them to dates. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=1472a62011eb9ddd72d2dfe881167891

Comment: I guess I was confused as I saw `::date` as a columnar operation, but that's not correct - it's applied to each text instance individually.

Comment: As soon as I try to add 01/20/2023 it throws up errors

Comment: @Perk8 the format of `01/20/2023` is different than the OP's formats.

Comment: How can I alter the code to accomodate 01/20/2023 and 01/20/23?

Comment: @Perk8 questions are not asked and answered in the comments section. Post a question where you describe your problem.